# Crashlytics doesn't verify if it is configured in app

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, crashlytics

I have installed the most recent plugin version for Android Studio and restarted Android Studio and followed the setup steps via the Crashlytics icon that has now appeared in the toolbar. Everything works fine until it gets the screen that tells me to "Launch your app!".. I launch the app (I've launched in RUN and DEBUG mode on a real device, the emulator and a genymotion simulator) but Crashlytics does not detect that it is configured and just stays there waiting. See the screenshot below for what screen I am referring to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the Android plugin for Crashlytics tries to add the following line for you in the main Activity of the app, but doesn't show an error if it is unable to.

```
Crashlytics.start(this);
```

Adding the line to the main Activity allows Crashlytics to verify the app.

Comment: have the same problem, but this unfortunately doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on linux in Android Studio, and well.. turning the computer off and on again fixed this. In the last step, where it says:

> Once launched we will verify Crashlytics is configured for your app

The back button was supposed to turn inactive while Fabric verified. This did not happen for me, until I turned the computer off and on again.

Answer (score 0):

Check :

```
 buildTypes {
        debug {
            **ext.enableCrashlytics = true**
        }

        release {
            **ext.enableCrashlytics = true**

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possible cause is the app had been deleted from same org before. One work around is putting the app to another org (with different ApiKey). I don't know how to revert app deleting (or whether it's possible).